# JQuery sibling shorthand

Tags: jquery, navigation

I am trying to detect an elements direct sibling using a short hand notation which I thought worked. The following is my code:

```
$menuContainer = $('<div></div>').attr('id', 'menuContainer').attr('class', 'menu-container'); //.hide();
$menuContainerInner = $('<div></div>').attr('class', 'container-inner');
$menuContainer.append($menuContainerInner);
$menuContainer.insertAfter($('div#block-views-Menu-block_1'));
$($menuContainer + ' > div.container-inner').css('background', 'red');
```

In the above code I dynamically create 2 div and assign them to variables for latter reference.
I embed the second div in the first.

So,  using `$($menuContainer + ' > div.container-inner').css('background', 'red');` I am trying to find and change the inner-div's background color without using the normal div-id's path.

Isn't there some notation that does this or am I mistaken??

Answer (score 1):

`$menuContainer` is an object, which you're going to implicitly call `toString` on, which probably isn't what you want.

I'd use [`children`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) instead:

```
$menuContainer.children('div.container-inner').css('background', 'red');
```

But if you like this (passing the object separately as the root) also works:

```
$('> div.container-inner', $menuContainer).css('background', 'red');
```

[Gratuitous live example](http://jsbin.com/udovip)

Answer (score 1):

"$menuContainer" seems to be a jquery object, not a string, I believe what you want is:

$menuContainer.children('.container-inner');

Answer (score 1):

Try using the context of the selector:

```
$('div.container-inner', $menuContainer).css('background', 'red');
```